# call a jquery function when user clicks jQueryUI modal dialog close button (x)?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using a jQuery modal dialog in my ASP .NET MVC 3 application,i want to call a simple jquery function when the user clicks the close button (X) of jQueryUI modal dialog

how can i handle that in my view

```
            "Cancel": function () {
                $('#divAddRecord').html('');
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
```

im doing this in the cancel button click, i want to do the same when the user clicks the close (X) button

Comment: `hide: { alert('modal closing'); }` you can see this in the documentation of jquery ui dialog.

Comment: you can add a click event handler when adding the buttons to your dialog: buttons: [
    {
      text: "Close",
      click: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );myfunction();
      }
    }
  ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
    close: function( event, ui ) { //your code }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".close" ).dialog({     
 close: function( event, ui ) {
 **your code here**
 }
});
```